# set scope based on the return response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

// html view

```
<div class="error" ng-show="error && error !== 'timeout' && !reset">Login failed</div>
```

in the js controller file I have some logic that basically does a POST ajax request and then returns the response, if the login has been unsuccessful I want to show the 'error' div above.

// js file

```
LoginService.prototype.signIn = function(email, password) {
    var url = $rootScope.rootDomain + '/user/login/new-ui';
    var extraParams = { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK', email: email, password: password };
    $http({
        url : url,
        method : 'POST',
        data : $.param(extraParams),
        headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })
        .then(function(data) {
            $localStorage.$reset();
            // get ajax response and if success is 0 then login failed, show a hidden div
            if ( data.data.success == 0 ) {
                $rootScope.error = true;
                return;
            }
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong within my javascript/angular file?

Comment: what do your network responses look like?

Comment: The html is in header part or it is relative to routing?

Answer (score 1):

You have a really high reputation, way above mine, so I shouldn't have to lecture you about separation of concerns, but, it looks like you have logic in your service (LoginService?) that really ought to belong in a controller. Either that or the naming is throwing me off. I also don't understand why you are using prototype. What's the purpose of that?

Further, setting properties on `$rootScope` is something that even noobs know not to do. So, I'll assume you already know all of that and that this example is one of those odd one-offs, where up is down and left is right and you just need to make it work...

It looks like you need to reference `$rootScope` properly in your template:

```
<div class="error" ng-show="$root.error && $root.error !== 'timeout' && !reset">Login failed</div>
```

That's not a typo. In a template you access `$rootScope` with `$root`. That threw me for a loop when I first saw it. Also, I can't see where `reset` is defined, so I'm assuming it's not important to the example.

Comment: Ah, that's a helpful FYI about $root; thanks for that! I would consider trimming this down to just the bit that makes this work properly, though, and leave the other parts to [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (though I have to admit, I'm resisting making suggestions too).